# Select value changes back to default after successful onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, html-select

I am implementing a form in which the user can dynamically add or remove dropdowns. Through the dropdown the user may manage the participants/voters.

After selecting a user, the selected user should not re-appear in the dropdown list, in the other available dropdowns.

The part with the dynamic dropdowns is exported to a new function component `VotingGroups`. In this component I am passing callbacks and two states (`groups`, `unselectedUsers`).

```
VotingGroups({
    groups,
    addGroup,
    deleteGroup,
    addVoterDropdown,
    removeVoterDropdown,
    saveVoter,
    saveGroupRate,
    unselectedUsers,
})
```

The users get updated within the `groups` state (check lower the `setGroups` line) and this works without any UI problems.

**BUG:**

After choosing a user/voter from the dropdown, I still see the default value **"Choose Voter"**. Only when I am updating the `unselectedUsers` state, is when I get the bug (by uncommenting the `setUnselectedUsers` line everything works). In debug mode, I see that the value gets changed to the one selected and after a few renders it changes back to default.

The `unselectedUsers` state gets also correctly updated.

This is how I update the both states (using setState hook) within the `saveVoter` callback:

```
setGroups(newGroups);
setUnselectedUsers(prevState => prevState.filter(user => user.uid !== newUser.uid))
```

Here is the select part:

```
<select className="form-control col-sm-4"
    name={"selectVoter"}
    value={voter?.user?.uid}
    onChange={(e) => saveVoter(
        e.target.value, groupIndex, dropdownIndex)}
    required>
    <option value="">Choose Voter</option>
    {
        unselectedUsers[0] !== undefined
            ? unselectedUsers.map((user) => {
                return (
                    <option key={user.uid}
                        value={user.uid}>{user.username}</option>
                )
            })
            : null
    }
</select>
```

Comment: useEffect(() => {
   // you can update state here so that will alway triggerred after group change
}, [groups])

Comment: @RohitKumar Unfortunatelly, this does not help. The `groups` state gets updated in the component one level higher which re-renders the `VotingGroups` component automatically with the updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution.

The problem lies in the html `<select>` part.

A dropdown can only show values that exist in the `<option><option/>` sections.

By only showing the `unselectedUsers` the dropdown was unable to show the selected user.

I only had to add the following line of code:

```
{ voter.user?.uid ? <option value={voter.user.uid}>{voter.user.username}</option> : null }
```

under the

```
<option value="">Choose Voter</option>
```